# how to replace the symbol with another symbol in a string

Tags: python-3.x

Question is to extract the details from the link and i want to replace the & symbol with : but i am not getting desried result.
this is what i tried

```
link="http://www.cleartrip.com/signin/service?username=test&pwd=test&profile=developer&role=ELITE&key=manager"
link=link.split("?")[1]
url=link.split("&")
for word in url:
    print(word.replace("&",":"))
```

My output:

```
username=test
pwd=test
profile=developer
role=ELITE
key=manager
```

expected output:

```
username: test
pwd: test
profile: developer
role: ELITE
key: manager
```

Comment: It looks like you actually want to replace `=` with `:`

Comment: sorry sorry my bad thanks anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
link="http://www.cleartrip.com/signin/service?username=test&pwd=test&profile=developer&role=ELITE&key=manager"
link=link.split("?")[1]
url=link.split("&")
for word in url:
    print(word.replace("=",":"))
```

Comment: Just replace    print(word.replace("&",":")) to print(word.replace("=",":"))